# How can I give names to output files which are similar to the name of the SAS script being executed?

Tags: sas

Assume that I have a SAS script file named "my_sas_script.sas". I want to add statements to that script so as to achieve the following:

---

### When the script is executed a variable should be created and the value of that variable should be "my_sas_script.sas". The variable type should preferably be **character** but the name of the variable is immaterial.

The purpose is to give names to output files which are similar to the name of the script without being forced to adapt the code whenever the name of the script is changed.

Comment: How are you running that sas **program**?  Are you running from the operating system command line?  Opening SAS Display Manager and editing the program file and submitting it?  Use some other non base SAS interface like SAS/Studio or Enterprise Guide or DIS?

Comment: https://support.sas.com/kb/24/301.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your SAS **program** from the command line:

```
sas my_sas_program.sas
```

Then you can just use the value of the SYSIN option.

```
%let program=%qsysfunc(getoption(sysin));
```

If you want to remove any path to the file that might be included use %SCAN().

```
%let program=%qscan(&program,-1,/\);
```